# O código roda, mas na hora de imprimir o código não mostra (Python)

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

def f(x):
  return (1400.0/x)*(1-(1+x)**-30.0) - 144000.0

def df(x):
   return 1400*((-1/(x**2))*(1-(1+x)**-30)+(30/((x+1)**31))*1/x)

def newton(x0, Er, it):
  x0 = float(3)
  it = 0
  itmax = 15
  Erro = 10**-4
  Er = 0
  while(Er >= Erro and it <= itmax):
    x1 = x - f(x0)/df(x0)
    x0 = x1
    Er = ((x0 - x1)/x0)
    it = it + 1
    print('A raíz é: ', x1)
```

Comment: O código pode até funcionar, mas são declarados 3 métodos e nenhum está sendo invocado pelo programa.

Comment: Como assim? Você pode me dizer oq eu poderia mudar?

Comment: Como o @G.Bittencourt disse, você possui 3 métodos ```f(x)```, ```df(x)``` e ```newton(x0, Er, it)```, você fez a declaração dos mesmos, no entanto não fez sua invocação, você pode encontrar alguns exemplos [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/funcoes-em-python/37340)

Answer (score -1):

Olá, tudo bom.

Para que alguma das funções funcione, ela precisa ser chamada fora do def. Mas há outros problemas com o seu código também. Por exemplo, na função "newton(x0, er, it)" você solicita três parâmetros ('x0', 'er' e 'it'), porém redefine todos eles assim que o método é chamado.

Outra coisa, dadas as suas definições para as variáveis que servirão de condição para o laço (while) continuar rodando, o programa jamais entrará neste laço, pois Er=0 e Erro=0.0001. Desta forma, Erro > Er, logo o laço não se iniciará e o print, que está dentro do laço, jamais será lido.